# Radio Buttons do not work if Angular Route is included on the page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Just as the title states, I have radio buttons. as soon as ng-route is included in the angular application, the radio buttons stop working.

Heres the code:

```
<html ng-app="vBackup">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular-route.js"></script>
<script>
// ============ Declare Application =========== //
var app = angular.module('vBackup', ['ngRoute']);
// ============ Route Providers =============== //
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: './ng/views/backup.html'
    }).when('/backup', {
        templateUrl: './ng/views/backup.html'
    }).when('/restore', {
        templateUrl: './ng/views/restore.html'
    }).when('/cloud', {
        templateUrl: './ng/views/cloud.html'
    }).when('/settings', {
        templateUrl: './ng/views/backup.html'
    })
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="nav">
        <div class="menu-item">
            <a href="#/backup"><input type="radio" name="navi" id="backup"><label for="backup">Backup</label></a>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-item">
            <a href="#/restore"><input type="radio" name="navi" id="restore"><label for="restore">Restore</label></a>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-item">
            <a href="#/cloud"><input type="radio" name="navi" id="cloud"><label for="cloud">Cloud</label></a>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="content" view-animate-container>
        <div ng-cloak ng-view class="view-animate wrapper">

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If I remove ng-route, all works fine.

Fiddle Demo
https://jsfiddle.net/rrLobqzv/3/

^ Oddly enough with this, if i put the external references into the fiddle editor, and move the controller code to the js pane all works as it shoudl but not when kept in tact as it would be on a real page.

Comment: This is happening because your radio button is being re-render again.

Comment: why? they are outside of the area in which the new view is rendered by the view controller. i was under the impression that elements outside the view container were not effected by a view change. isnt that the point of the MVC aspect?

Comment: But inside of your app `<html ng-app="vBackup">`

Comment: okay so whats the solution? Placing the radio buttons outside of `ng-app="vBackup"` stops the buttons from changing views in the application